# Rails - Delayed job stops running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job, openshift

I'm developing this **[application](http://actibities-uniongr.rhcloud.com/pages/view-demo)** which I have deployed to OpenShift.

I have "moved" the actual user registration process to a delayed job because there are a lot of stuff taking placing during this. Every two days (or so), the delayed job process stops running.

In the logs I find this:

`Error while reserving job: closed MySQL connection`

I tried starting it with the following command:

`RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job -m start`

but the problem still exists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to your database.yml

```
reconnect: true
```

I am not sure if this will fix your problem, but its worth trying.

Also, have a look at this [MySql documentation about lost connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-lost-connection.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem (not using OpenShift). After I tried the command you said, I still had a problem. Then I restarted delayed_job like so:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job stop
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start
```

and the problem went away. In my case the problem was that delayed_job was looking for a method that no longer exists and simply needed to be restarted. Maybe this helps.
I also tried Vimsha's answer on development and not on production and it didn't effect the result for me.